# How to select a button by its text using selenium 4.8

Tags: python, selenium, automation, linkedin-api

I am trying to automate contact request on Linkedi with Python and Selenium. I'm stuck on the part ADD CONCTACT because I don't know how to select a button based on it's visible text. The tutorial that I'm following doesn't provide the right syntaxt. As you can see in my code I've tried a lot of options already.
I have tried this so far but it doesn't work:

```
all_buttons = Select.select_by_visible_text('Suivre')
#all_buttons = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@text='Suivre']")
# driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
# all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
```

Here is the HTML for the button

```
<button aria-label="Invitez XYZ à rejoindre votre réseau" id="ember369" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Se connecter
</span></button>

<!---->
<!---->
```

Here is my code (still doesn't work)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
url='https://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)

driver =
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')
time.sleep(2)

#LOG IN 

username = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@name='session_key']")
password = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@name='session_password']")

username.send_keys('MY EMAIL')
password.send_keys('MY PASSWORD')
time.sleep(2)


submit = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@type='submit']").click()

time.sleep(5)


# ADD CONTACTS

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?sid=0tK")
time.sleep(5)


all_buttons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Se connecter']")

connect_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons]

for btn in connect_buttons:
    btn.click()
```

Comment: ```button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Suivre']")```

Comment: We can see the `code` but can you add the `HTML` for the element too, this will easy for us to give you correct answer.

Comment: Yes sorry, when I added more code Stackoverflow told me that I was spamming. I'll add the code and HTML in my question

Answer (score 1):

I can spot 2 mistakes you make in this code.

```py
all_buttons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Se connecter']")

connect_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons]

for btn in connect_buttons:
    btn.click()
```

Firstly `driver.find_element()` will return only one element, so you can't iterate over it. Instead use `driver.find_elements()` if you want to get multiple elements.

Secondly your XPath locator `//button[text()='Se connecter']` looks for a "button" element with the exact text 'Se connecter', but the element containing the text is the SPAN element inside of the button and the SPAN element itself contains white space from what I can tell.

You should try using `//span[contains(text(),'Se connecter')]`.
`contains()` will match if the item contains the text, not just exact matches.